# Return a default value beside existing entity in database

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have an API that would return a list of entities. I want to return a default value that represent a null entity but not actually an entity in database. How to achieve such result in Django restframework ?

I tried to create an entity that represent a null entity but that solution didn't meet the requirement